# Why Chrome Extension wont return Google Search API results?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building this Google Chrome extension that will override Chrome Browser homepage with custom google search engine.

This custom google search engine suppose to returns the result from the query that the user entered. To test this, i first build the html version of this custom search engine first and it works well. Below is the screenshot :

[image]

But when i tried to make it as the chrome extension, it fails with no search results being returned.

**here is my main.html :**

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<TITLE>Search or Share</TITLE>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<center>


<div id="page-wrap">
<div style="height:30px"></div>

<center>
    <div id="logo"><img src="logo.png" /></div>
    <input type="text" title="Real Time Search" id="searchbox" name="searchbox"/>
</center>
<br/><br/>
<div id="search-content">   
    <div class="content" style="width:600px; display:inline">
        <div class="header">Web</div>
        <div class="data" id="web-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</center>
<div id="footer">
Copyright &copy; 2013
</div>
</BODY>
<SCRIPT src="main.js"></SCRIPT>

</HTML>
```

**and here is my manifest.json :**

```
{
  "name": "Search or Share",
  "version": "0.2",
  "incognito": "split",
   "background": { 
    "scripts": ["jquery-1.9.1.js","search.js","main.js"] 
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://www.google.com/*"
  ],
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "main.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**here is my search.js** :

```
google.load('search','1');
```

**and this last one is my main.js file :**

```
// Define variables
var webSearch;
var lastSearch = 0;

//Init function
$(function () { 
    webSearch = new google.search.WebSearch();
    webSearch.setSearchCompleteCallback(this, webSearchComplete, [webSearch, lastSearch]);

    $('#searchbox').focus();
});

// Begin search on keyup (realtime)
$('#searchbox').keyup(function () {
    var query = $(this).val();
    search(query);
});

// Search for the query 
function search(query) {
    if (query.length > 0) {
        $("#search-content").show();
    } else {
        $("#search-content").hide();
    }
    webSearch.execute(query);
}


function webSearchComplete(searcher, searchNum) {
    var contentDiv = document.getElementById('web-content');
    contentDiv.innerHTML = '';
    var results = searcher.results;
    var newResultsDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newResultsDiv.id = 'web-content';
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var result = results[i];
        var resultHTML = '<div style="height:70px; margin-top:5px;">';
        resultHTML += '<a href="' + result.unescapedUrl + '" target="_blank"><b>' + result.titleNoFormatting + '</b></a><br/>' + result.content + '<div/>';
        newResultsDiv.innerHTML += resultHTML;
    }
    contentDiv.appendChild(newResultsDiv);
}
```

*i have made the jsapi.js script too, but it is too long so i dont post it here.

Why is this happening? is it because chrome wont allow any interaction with the outside server on its homepage or what? Thanks!

Comment: Move your inline script to a seperate JS file. Open the console for your extension page, and you would have seen a warning about violation of the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).

Comment: ok, i have done like what you said, moving my inline scripts to seperate js file (see above for the changes) but still the search results wont come out. What else could i have possibly done wrong? thanks!

Comment: `http://www.google.com/` -> `http://www.google.com/*`. Check the errors in the console, you'll be able to debug a large part of the problem yourself.

Comment: hm thats not working either. could you tell me which errors console that you were talking about? because i never use any.

Comment: @ryzan The console of the Chrome developer tools, for your extension page. Press F12 if you're on Windows or Linux, press ⌥⌘J if you're on Mac.

Comment: oh thanks for the info. And after i checked, i got error of "Refused to load the script 'http://www.google.com/uds/?file=search&v=1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:"." . Is that means it is not possible for me to make this extension?

Comment: Read the relevant API docs and see whether it's possible to load the https version of the API. If it's possible, whitelist this https URL in the manifest file.

Comment: hi..thanks so much! now everythings works like charm! it appears that i just need to add this to my manifest.json : "permissions": [ "https://*.google.com/*"],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'",

Comment: @ryzalyusoff could you please share your code .I also have to make something similar so that i can get some hint.

Comment: @BhawnaMalhotra sure. Take a look at the blogpost i made here: http://goo.gl/ES2rZT . Feel free to read or download the code there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Rob W, now my problem is solved. It seems I need to do two things to get this thing working correctly.

First, I need to link the jsapi with the https protocol.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Then, I need to edit the manifest.json file to give permission to any search link from google.com with the https protocol, and specify content_security_policy.

```
  "permissions": [ "https://*.google.com/*"],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'",
```